# What do the different colours of sound mean?

Tags: rhythm-thief

In Rhythm Thief and the Emperor's Treasure, you can collect various sounds as you wander around. They get used for little quests, and for making the Master Instrument.

I have noticed that there are 4 colours of sounds - red, yellow, blue, and green. Does the colour have any significance?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. It's just a rough category. You can see Yellow has all the animal sounds, while blue has mostly ambient synthetic/mechanical sounds.